# Extract data points from a dataframe based on correlation threshold in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, purrr, lubridate

I have a dataframe with two columns say X and Y. How can we extract certain number of rows from this dataframe that gives correlation between X and Y less than a certain threshold? For example, I want to extract 10 rows from the dataframe given below such that correlation between X and Y is less than 0.4.

```
df <- structure(list(X = c(0.47, 0.4723, 0.4747, 0.4771, 0.4794, 0.4818, 0.4842, 0.4866, 0.4889, 0.4913, 0.4937, 0.4961, 0.4984, 0.5008, 0.5032, 0.5103, 0.5173, 0.5244, 0.5315, 0.5386, 0.5457, 0.5527, 0.5598, 0.5709, 0.582, 0.593, 0.6041, 0.6152, 0.6263, 0.6373), Y = c(NaN, 255.5, 440, 110.5, 197.25, 438, 100, 467.75, 483.5, 492.25, 489.25, 503, 511.25, 508.25, 505, 511, 503.33, 501, 509.25, 508.25, 165.33, 102, 461.25, 392, 530.75, 537.75, NaN, 601, 523, 120)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also, if multiple sets of such data points satisfy the above condition then I would like to extract all such possible sets.

Comment: FYI, there are `choose(30, 10)` - 30 million+ possible 10 row sets from your 30 rows.

Comment: Correct! I guess there should be some smart way to search in the data.

Comment: What about a correlation of -.9? That is below .4.  Since you example produces a correlation of .099 after removing two rows with NaNs, you need to select 18 of the remaining rows: `cor(df.mat[sample(rows, 18), ])[1, 2]`. A few will be over .4, but just skip over those.

Comment: @dcarlson Set corresponding to corr of -0.9 will also satisfy condition of corr < 0.4. Can you please elaborate more on what you did above.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your `df`:

```
df <- na.omit(df)         # Remove rows with NA/NaN 
df.mat <- as.matrix(df)   # Convert to matrix for `cor`
rows <- row.names(df.mat) # Get row names for sampling
cor(df.mat)[1, 2]         # Get correlation
# [1] 0.09961473
set.seed(42)              # Set seed for this example
(sub <- sample(rows, 18))
#  [1] "18" "6"  "2"  "26" "11" "5"  "19" "30" "16" "8"  "24" "29" "15" "23" "25" "3"  "4"  "10"
cor(df.mat[sub, ])[1, 2]
# [1] 0.1082971
(sub <- sample(rows, 18))
# [1] "26" "29" "5"  "6"  "14" "30" "21" "3"  "9"  "4"  "2"  "11" "23" "15" "12" "7"  "18" "17"
cor(df.mat[sub, ])[1, 2]
# [1] 0.07151581
```